# Его высочество - это "оно" или "он"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Например: "Его высочество уехал(о) на родину". Вопрос вдогонку: если рассматривать обращение на "вы", то обязательно ли писать "их высочество"? Нельзя так: "Его высочество уехали на родину"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Его высочество - это ***он*** (видно из местоимения). При полном упоминании особы за этим следует и титул мужского рода; если же при неформальном упрощении текста он опускается, то грамматический **род глагола** остаётся мужским ("ЕВ /такой-то/ уех**ал**"). Множественному обращению "вы" соответствует в 3-м лице "*их высочеств**а***" и множественное число глагола (речь идёт о *нескольких* лицах равного положения).

Answer (score 1):

Alex_ander прав, однако... я множество раз наблюдала множественное число у сказуемых:

> — Ваше высочество очень благосклонны ко мне, – поклонился Бекингэм.
> <...> — Что же вы слышали, ваше высочество? — спросил он. — Что так
> поразило вас?

[Виконт де Бражелон. Книга вторая](https://books.google.ru/books?id=054aAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT6&lpg=PT6&dq=%D0%98%20%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E,%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%83%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0,%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0,%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=3HCV_r2yo4&sig=GvyAIvy8wQ1uY3sF6kG6I-ZRuOA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivusni2tTdAhXLhiwKHdUOCyYQ6AEwBXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

---

> Правительствующій Сенатъ приказали: для Императорскаго Величества
> многолѣтнаго здравія и дабы Господъ Богъ даровалъ отъ скорьби Его
> Величеству облегченіе, приказали Шляхетству, всѣмъ тѣмъ, которые по
> указамъ Его...

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Суворов и Кутузов (сборник)](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Wqa9BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT411&dq=%D0%98%D1%85%20%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPlKyE3tTdAhVIEiwKHcWABp4Q6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q&f=false)

---

О [прописных/строчных](https://gramotno.livejournal.com/18979.html) при упоминании титулов:

> В официальных документах корректно: *Его Императорское Величество, Ваша
> Светлость* и т. п. В остальных случаях корректно: *его величество, ваша
> светлость, их превосходительства.*
>
> Обращение необходимо писать с прописных при упоминании полного титула
> в официальных документах: генеалогическое древо, письмо к монарху,
> приказ с его подписью *(Его Величество король Людовик XIV)*. Если же к
> королю обращаются в устной форме *(Приказание вашего величества
> выполнено!)* или просто упоминают его в беседе *(Мне удалось поговорить
> с его величеством...),* обращение пишется строчными.
>
> В переносных
> выражениях (его величество случай) также используются строчные буквы.
>
> Написание «Его величество» (с прописной только первое слово) корректно
> в том случае, если местоимение стоит в начале предложения. Все
> вышесказанное относится ко всем королевским и дворянским титулам.

Comment: Множественности 3 лица - из старинного (времён становления обращения на "вы") подобострастия типа "барин извол**я**т". Во втором же лице (первая цитата) отклонений нет (/вы/ ваше величество благосклонны) - там не "оно" как предлагалось в вопросе. Средний род глаголов при величествах с высочествами может употребляться только с иронией или издёвкой.

Comment: Дык я ж разве спорю? О_о